# Without using arrays and special method, how do I make an nthWord method?

Tags: java

Without using arrays and special methods, like the `split` method, how do I write the following method: The input int represents a number `n` that is assumed to be positive, and the output string contains every nth word of the input string, starting with the first word, separated by a single space.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static String nthWord(int n, String s1) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int x = 0; x < s1.length(); x = x + n) {
      sb.append(s1.charAt(x));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

So, for instance, the input:

> HW2.nthWord(3, "zero one     two  three four five six seven")

Should output:

> "zero three six"

But my current method outputs:

> "zon t heo vs v"

Answer (score 2):

You need to check each character of the string to find the spaces in order to identify the words.  So what you have is a start, but you need to:

1. Increment x by 1 only.
2. For each character, check if it is a space and keep track of which word you are on.
3. When you hit a space, increment your word counter (or reset it to 0 if it is a multiple of n)
4. Add the characters to your string when your word counter is at 0.

Comment: A good answer. 
Let's divide the process into two.
1. Traversing the string and keeping track of i for current ith word (and start of the word).
2. Checking the i if it equals n and resetting it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to keep track of are the last character and the word index. The logic is pretty straight forward.

- Iterate through all characters
- If the last character is space and the current character is not
  space, then that's  a new word (increment word index).
- If the word index is divisible by n, that's the word you want.
- When you encounter the word you want, which is not the first, put a
  space.
- If the current word is what you want, append the current character.
- Remember to update the last character

Code:

```
 public static String nthWord(int n,String s1)
 {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     char lastChar = ' ';
     int wordIndex = -1;
     for(int i = 0 ; i < s1.length(); i++)
     {
         char c = s1.charAt(i);

         if(c != ' ' && lastChar == ' ')
         {
             wordIndex++;
             if(wordIndex > 0 && ((wordIndex % n) == 0))
             {
                 sb.append(' ');
             }
         }
         if(c != ' ' && ((wordIndex % n) == 0))
         {
             sb.append(c);
         }
         lastChar = c;
     }
     return sb.toString();
 }
```